# MySQL group by with conditional where clause

Tags: mysql, group-by

Please consider the following table structure:

`id | group | meta_1 | meta_2 |
1  | 1     | null   | null   |
2  | 1     | foo    | null   |
3  | 1     | null   | bar    |
4  | 2     | null   | null   |
5  | 2     | foo    | null   |
6  | 2     | null   | bar    |`

You can see that I have 6 rows, 3 of which belong to `group` 1, and 3 of which belong to `group` 2.

I would like to select 1 row from the first group, and 1 row from the 2nd group. However, a simple `GROUP BY group` is not sufficient, because the actual row returned in each group must be dependent on the following rules:

- if the value given for `meta_1` in the query is not null, and matches against a row, then return that row from the group
- otherwise, if the value given for `meta_2` in the query is not null, and matches against a row, then return that row for the group
- otherwise, return the row where both `meta_1` and `meta_2` are null

Such that the following given parameters:

`meta_1 = foo
meta_2 = bar`

Will return:

`id | group | meta_1 | meta_2 |
1  | 1     | foo    | null   |
5  | 2     | foo    | null   |`

because they match `meta_1 = foo`, and the following:

`meta_1 = baz
meta_2 = bar`

Will return:

`id | group | meta_1 | meta_2 |
3  | 1     | null   | bar    |
6  | 2     | null   | bar    |`

because `meta_1 = baz` does not match, so it falls back to `meta_2` which does match. And finally:

`meta_1 = baz
meta_2 = bob`

or

`meta_1 = null
meta_2 = null`

Will both return:

`id | group | meta_1 | meta_2 |
1  | 1     | null   | null   |
3  | 2     | null   | null   |`

as no `meta_*` match was made.

Can anyone please suggest how I can implement this conditional logic and combine it with a group by.

**Update**

I think I have solved this with the query below, note the order of precedence is defined by the order in which I write the `SELECT` queries:

`SELECT id, group, meta_1, meta_2
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE meta_1 <=> 'foo'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE meta_2 <=> 'bar'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE meta_1 IS NULL AND meta_2 IS NULL
) derived_table
GROUP BY group;`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show the expected result from your sample data set?

Comment: Ollie Jones - I have expanded on the expected result sets